# Poset of a given set

Tags: order-theory, well-orders

When we say "inclusion relation is a partial ordering on the power set of a set $S$", what will happen when cardinality of set $S$ is less than $3$? If it has at most 2 elements, how can we infer transitivity of power set?

Comment: I misunderstood, transitivity follows vacuously. Also note it's on the powerset, not the set itself.

Comment: What you mean by that? Furthermore, if given set $S$ was an empty set, could we state that it was still poset?

Comment: @AnarRzayev: The power set of $\varnothing$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, which is not empty. And yes, it is still partially ordered by $\subseteq$: $\subseteq$ on $\{\varnothing\}$ is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Aha, so can we conclude that $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is poset, where $A$ is empty set, or just contains an element?

Comment: @AnarRzayev: Yes, $\langle\wp(A),\subseteq\rangle$ is always a partial order, no matter what set $A$ is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So regardless of given set $A$, whether it is an empty set, or singleton, it will always yield that $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a partial order, right?
Note: Thanks!

Comment: @AnarRzayev: Yes: $A$ can be any set at all.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I just wanted to elaborate on $1$ thing: Can we say $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a total order when $A$ is an empty set (power set will contain only one element)?

Comment: @AnarRzayev: Yes; see my comment on your new question.